# Bookmarked muc rooms do not get loaded on frontend aplication

Tags: ejabberd

When i insert a bookmark data directly on Ejabberd database on table **private_storage**, my frontend application do not load the information when a logged whit my user. But if i save bookmark with my frontend then the bookmarked rooms are shown when i logged.

Ejabberd use more info then that table to refer bookmarked rooms data? There is a way to automatic bookmark a room when the user open this?

Example of bookmark data inserted in database table **private_storage** column **data**:

```
<storage xmlns='storage:bookmarks'/>
  <conference
   autojoin='true' 
   jid='test@conference.test.exemple.com'
   name='Test'>
    <nick>Test Load Room</nick>
  </conference>
</storage>
```

Answer (score 0):

> if i save bookmark with my frontend then the bookmarked rooms are shown when i logged.

Then you should check what other effects apply in ejabberd when you do this using your frontend.

You should also look how does that frontend client store the bookmark: maybe it uses a custom format?

I tested using Tkabber client: when it stores a bookmark for a room, only the private table is updated.

I then tried to set a bookmark using this API call. Only the private table is updated, and Tkabber gets the bookmark correctly, and the client joins the room atuomatically when it logins.

```
$ ejabberdctl private_set user1 localhost "<storage xmlns='storage:bookmarks'><conference jid='sala1@muc.localhost' name='sala1' autojoin='true'><nick>user1</nick></conference></storage>"
```

$ ejabberdctl private_set user1 localhost "user1"